# angular if all model values are not null show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to show text based on each of the input's in my form having a value entered or a box ticked.

I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work for all the input fields.

Any ideas?

```
<div class="container" ng-app ng-controller="OrderFormController">
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="well">
            <label for="description" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Extinguisher Status</label>
            <div ng-if="myForm.inputs != null">show something</div>
            <div class="input-group"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form name="myForm">
        <div class="row form-group" ng-repeat="input in inputs">
            <div class="well">
                <label for="description" class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{input.name}}</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Enter {{input.name}}" ng-model="entered">
                    <!-- <span type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" ng-if="input.name==' Geo Location:'"></span> -->
                    <span ng-class="{'input-group-addon danger' : !entered, 'input-group-addon success': entered}" ng-init="isActive = false">
              <span ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-remove': !entered, 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok': entered}" ng-init="isActive = false">
              </span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-group" ng-repeat="check in checks">
            <div class="well">
                <label for="description" class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{check.name}}</label>
                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label ng-class="{'btn btn-danger': !isActive, 'btn btn-success': isActive}" ng-init="isActive = false" ng-click="isActive = !isActive">
                        <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" required ng-model="entered"> <span ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-remove': !isActive, 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok': isActive}" ng-init="isActive = false" ng-click="isActive = !isActive">
                </span>

                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function OrderFormController($scope) {

    $scope.inputs = [{
        name: 'Fire Extinguisher Number:',
        id: 1,
        active: false
    }, {
        name: 'Extinguisher Location:',
        id: 2,
        active: false
    }, {
        name: 'Geo Location:',
        id: 3,
        active: false
    }];


    $scope.checks = [{
        name: 'Visual Inspection:',
        id: 4,
        active: false
    }, {
        name: 'Weight:',
        id: 5,
        active: false
    }, {
        name: 'Gague:',
        id: 6,
        active: false
    }, {
        name: 'Hose:',
        id: 7,
        active: false
    }, {
        name: 'Service Complete:',
        id: 8,
        active: false
    }];

}
```

Comment: When and how do you want to "show text"?

Comment: <div  ng-if="myForm.inputs != null">show something</div>

i am trying to show this line based on all the input text and checkboxes having a value or being true etc.

Comment: So everythin should be filled in or checked?

Comment: exactly then i can show at the top say a green class or text, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best what you can do, is to bind input fields and checkboxes to properties of the objects `$scope.inputs` and `$scope.checks` respectively. Like this:

for inputs:

```
<div class="row form-group" ng-repeat="input in inputs">
    <div class="well">
        <label for="description" class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{input.name}}</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Enter {{input.name}}" ng-model="input.value" />
            <span ng-class="{'input-group-addon danger' : !input.value, 'input-group-addon success': input.value}">
                <span ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-remove': !input.value, 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok': input.value}"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and like this for checks:

```
<div class="row form-group" ng-repeat="check in checks">
    <div class="well">
        <label for="description" class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{check.name}}</label>
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label ng-class="{'btn btn-danger': !check.active, 'btn btn-success': check.active}" ng-click="check.active = !check.active">
                <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" required="" ng-model="check.active" />
                <span ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-remove': !check.active, 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok': check.active}"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After that it's easy to check that everything is entered and selected:

```
$scope.isValid = function() {
    var inputsFilled = $scope.inputs.every(function(el) {
        return el.value;
    });
    var allChecked = $scope.checks.every(function(el) {
        return el.active;
    });
    return inputsFilled && allChecked;
};
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-if="isValid()">show something</div>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/HDYK7cJqN8jkLvQmojB0?p=info